# Sails fails to load when using remote Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

My Sail app runs when connecting to my local mongo db, but when I try and connect using a db hosted at Modulus, it won't load properly.

I have set the connection properly and tested it via it IDE

```
connections.js:
    // MONGO DB reference for the database
    cogspeed: {
    adapter   : 'sails-mongo',
    //host      : 'localhost',
    host      : 'novus.modulusmongo.net',
    port      : 27017,
    user      : '*********',
    password  : '***********',
    database  : '**********'
  },
```

The error I get is:

```
C:\Projects\gmm\cogspeed>sails lift

info: Starting app...

error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\gmm\cogspeed\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\conne
ction\server.js:553:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\gmm\cogspeed\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\conne
ction\connection_pool.js:140:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\gmm\cogspeed\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\con
nection\connection.js:512:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
```

Why is Sails still looking at localhost?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what does your `/config/models.js` file look like?

Comment: The /config/models.js is:
module.exports.models = {
 
  // Your app's default connection.
  // i.e. the name of one of your app's connections (see `config/connections.js`)
  //
  // (defaults to localDiskDb)
  connection: 'cogspeed-mongo'
};

Comment: The culprit turned out to be the /config/local.js file that had a mongo adapter that was pointing to the localhost.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. As it turned out, having more than one connections in connections.js with the **same adapter** causes this issue.  I'm on sails 0.10.5

Comment: Yes. I just commented the `localDiskDb` and  left my `someMongodbServer`   and it worked.

Comment: This issue is still in v0.11 of Sailsjs.

Answer (score 3):

Verify that your password does NOT contain a '@' character. Due to the current implementation of node-mongodb-native it messes up your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

The /config/local.js file still had an adapter for mongo that was pointing to the localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Sails still (v 0.11.0) has the issue with having several adapters of the same type in the */config/connections.js* configuration file. I had the same problem after deploying on Modulus and the support couldn't help me. I spent hours trying to debug it.... But the workaround is really simple. Instead of putting db connection parameters into *connections.js*, put them directly into the environment specific configuration files like this:

```
// config/env/development.js
module.exports = {

  connections : {
       mongo: {
          adapter: 'sails-mongo',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 27017,
          database: 'your-db-name'
      },
  },
  // your other dev configs
};
```

for production:

```
// config/env/development.js
module.exports = {

  connections : {
       mongo: {
          adapter: 'sails-mongo',
          host: 'your-remote-mongo-host',
          port: 27017,
          user: 'your-remote-user',
          password: 'your-remote-db-password',
          database: 'your-remote-db-name'
      },
  },
  // your other dev configs
};
```

And your */config/models.js* looks then like this:

```
module.exports = {

  connection : 'mongo',

  // your other model configs
};
```

PS: This issue has been already reported to the sails.js team https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2480

Answer (score 0):

If the error says

```
error: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

then, *Mongo* is not running. You can start it with the command

```
mongod
```

silly mistake, but also happens...

---

If the error says error: `MongoError: auth fails`, then maybe this solution can work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29335121/2615737