# sails-mongo auth error in sails 0.10

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

Using "sails-mongo": "^0.10.0-rc2", "sails": "~0.10.0-rc4" I'm getting the following error on `sails lift`.

```
verbose: Loading adapter ( sails-mongo ) for algorithm  from `node_modules` directory...
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
verbose: Starting ORM...
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: MongoError: auth fails
    at Object.toError (/home/default/Projects/machine_learning_data_sets/machine-learning-    engine/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:110:11)
    at /home/default/Projects/machine_learning_data_sets/machine-learning-    engine/node_modules/sails-    mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/auth/mongodb_cr.js:39:33
    at /home/default/Projects/machine_learning_data_sets/machine-learning-engine/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1806:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/home/default/Projects/machine_learning_data_sets/machine-    learning-engine/node_modules/sails-    mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:442:41)
    at /home/default/Projects/machine_learning_data_sets/machine-learning-    engine/node_modules/sails-    mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:485:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/home/default/Projects/machine_learning_data_sets/machine-    learning-engine/node_modules/sails-    mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/default/Projects/machine_learning_data_sets/machine-learning-    engine/node_modules/sails-        mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:443:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/default/Projects/machine_learning_data_sets/machine-learning-    engine/node_modules/sails-    mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:191:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
verbose: Lowering sails...
verbose: Sent kill signal to child process (12033)...
verbose: Shutting down socket server...
verbose: Shutting down HTTP server...
```

This is on a local mongodb that is reachable in the mongo console.

my connection is configured by

```
  mongo: {
    adapter   : 'sails-mongo',
    host      : 'localhost',
    port      : 27017,
    user      : '',
    password  : '',
    database  : 'mle'
  },
```

Comment: Try removing the blank `user` and `password`?

Comment: Didn't make a difference. I'm pretty sure I've messed something up again, seems someone had a very similar issue with a 0.9.x version of sails some time ago though.

Comment: a clean sails 0.10.0-rc4 install works just fine with the above config ... I've definitely screwed up somewhere (probably in the last migration)

Comment: got it. I didn't remove the sample mongo connection before adding my own, even though it wasn't used by any model, it still got called.  I should probably get myself a rubber duck and talk to it for a couple of hours before posting questions.

Comment: If that's the case--that the sample mongo connection was being called without being used by any models--you should definitely post it as an issue on the [Sails GitHub repository](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues).  Connections are only supposed to be used when a model is connecting to them.

Comment: Issue submitted [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1574).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case i am using url for connect mongodb like below

```
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
url: 'mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>/<DATABASE>'
```

Comment: Haven't tested this, since the project i was working on has long ended and moved to using django but the solution seems plausible so I went ahead and confirmed it...

Answer (score 1):

mongo: {
    adapter   : 'sails-mongo',
    host      : 'localhost',
    port      : 27017,
    user      : '',`user: 'username', //optional`
    password  : '',`password: 'password', //optional`
    database  : 'mle'
  },

user name and password are optional so don't need to give ,just comment it and run it .it's work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with various sails release candidates when I forgot to update to the matching sails-mongo package.  You might update to the latest, sails 0.10.5 and sails-mongo 0.10.4.  These work together.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I couldn't connect to an imported database, even though I tried by creating a lot of different users, with different roles.

So I run `db.system.users.find()`, and I notice a user, that I haven't created it. It was something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("546699985feb7553f2e4dc32"), "user" : "newuser", "pwd" : "aaacf6ead2f12cbeb1a155b3021a3cda", "roles" : [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] }
```

So I went to the *connections.js* file, and after asking the old programmer what was the password for that user, and updated the username, and password.

Then just run `sails lift`, and luckily it had worked !

Answer (score 0):

You have probably troubles with your bson extension which is not loaded.

Your First Error:

> Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Multiples origin possibles: bson or node-gyp unloaded or database is not present.

To solve an error providen by depedencies (please check each time you use a solution and stop reading me if any one succeed):

First Solution in the root directory of your application:

```
npm install
```

If it don't works second solution if you are on OSX:

```
xcode-select --install
rm -rf node_modules // OR npm update
npm cache clean // OR npm update
npm install // OR npm update
```

On Ubuntu the second solution:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential
rm -rf node_modules // OR npm update
npm cache clean // OR npm update
npm install // OR npm update
```

Third solution if you think that bson is not présent under depedencies:

```
npm install bson
```

Maybe this one can save you if other doesn't work:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

After it if it doesn't work:

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson.git
cd js-bson
npm install
node-gyp rebuild
```

Sorry for this wtf answer but it could help you or someone else.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can connect to DB like this.

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-datastores

```
 // config/datastores.js
    module.exports.datastores = {
      default: {
        adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
        url: 'mysql://root:squ1ddy@localhost:3306/my_dev_db_name',
      }
    };
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts regarding your answer: 1. It's a bit late (6 years give or take); 2. It refers to sails v1 documentation, not v0.10 which was used for the question; 3. it suggests using mysql while the question is specific to mongodb. That being said, thanks for trying to help.